# Instalar StartBootstrap-SB-Admin usando Yarn

Tags: php, webpack, yarn, symfony4

Estou criando um esqueleto base para minhas aplicações e pretendo usar [Symfony 4](https://symfony.com) e [Startbootstrap-SB-Admin](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/).
Já tenho um projeto esqueleto usando `Symfony 3` e `SB-Admin-2` e mais outro com `Silex`. Esses ultimos eu criei usando `bower` dentro do *document_root*.

Agora estou usando [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) e [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org) através do [Webpack Encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html).

Estou com dificuldades de integrar ao CSS e JS compilados as libs necessárias do SB-Admin.

Instalei o Node 8, o Yarn e em seguida executei os comandos abaixo no Windows.

```
yarn add popper.js
yarn add @symfony/webpack-encore --dev
yarn add sass-loader node-sass --dev
yarn add jquery --dev
yarn add bootstrap-sass --dev
yarn add startbootstrap-sb-admin --dev
```

Os módulos foram incluídos em
***~node_modules/* ***

> NOTA: Estou usando Vagrant com um diretorio compartilhado Windows/Linux e em Linux os comandos do Yarn tentam criar symlinks para o webpack o que não é suportado pelo filesystem gerando o erro abaixo.
>
> ***error*** An unexpected error occurred: "EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../../../../webpack/bin/webpack.js' -> '/vagrant/skel/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/node_modules/.bin/webpack'"

#### Abaixo algumas linhas dos arquivos

***~templates/layout.html.twig***

```
<!-- Application CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/app.css') }}">
<!-- App main JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
```

***~assets/js/app.js***

```
require('../css/app.scss');

var $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');
require('startbootstrap-sb-admin/scss/sb-admin.scss');
```

***~assets/css/app.scss***

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
$brand-primary: darken(#428bca, 20%);
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
// Tentei usar import aqui
// @import '~startbootstrap-sb-admin/scss/sb-admin.scss';
```

#### PROBLEMA

Empaquei na inclusão da linha abaixo no meu arquivo `.js` em meu `assets`

```
  require('startbootstrap-sb-admin/scss/sb-admin.scss');
```

Quando executo `c:\projetos\skel> yarn run encore dev` tudo ocorre bem, mas não percebo a inclusão dos CSSes nem dos JSes do tema nos arquivos finais compilados.

Answer (score 1):

No seu **~assets/js/app.js** tente usar o `import` ao invés do `require`

```
import 'startbootstrap-sb-admin/scss/sb-admin.scss';
```

Não se esqueça de rodar `$ yarn run encore dev` depois de efetuar essa atualização.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei descobrindo o problema de não funcionar com a sequencia que estava usando.

A atual versão do Startbootstrap-SB-Admin já está utilizando Bootstrap 4 enquanto que o bootstrap-sass ainda está sendo instalado como Bootstrap 3.
Então na verdade estava tudo acontecendo como deveria exceto pelo fato de que o SB-Admin não funciona mais com Bootstrap 3.

Então adicionei o bootstrap mais atual com `yarn add bootstrap --dev` e alterei a linha `require('bootstrap-sass');` para `require('bootstrap');` e então tudo começou a funcionar normalmente.

Como ficou o arquivo ***~assets/js/app.js***

```
require('../css/app.scss');
var $ = require('jquery');
require('fontawesome');
require('bootstrap');
require('startbootstrap-sb-admin/js/sb-admin');
```

e o arquivo ***~assets/css/app.scss***

```
$icon-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts/";
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
$brand-primary: darken(#428bca, 20%);
@import '~startbootstrap-sb-admin/vendor/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~startbootstrap-sb-admin/scss/sb-admin.scss';
```